# Yii 1.1.14 absoluteAuthTimeout

Tags: time, yii, logout, author

I download 1.1.14,and try it , get a question about user authTimeout
 Any one can help me?
 When i used the configration
 like this:

```
'comments'=array(
`user`=array(
...
'absoluteAuthTimeout' => 60*100,
...
```

and logined, but ,click user pannel at once , it logout auto.

Regards

Comment: What is your issue ?? the user must not log out automatically ??

Comment: No,just counter to that , it 'automatically too fast' ,I even can't do anything ,though a authenticatd user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement Session Timeout in the config file like

```
'components' => array(
   'session' => array(
      'timeout' => 300,
   ),
),
```

Comment: ok,I updated the lasted version,but ,it looks like a bug.But your advice is a way to process that question.Thanks!

Comment: If you're interesting in it ,please check out the new version 1.1.14,and find out that it's a bug or not.Wish comment.

Comment: this timeout setting is applicable to all cookies used in application?